# Shutdown button in menu does nothing in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, shutdown, console-kit

I have a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 in which the "Shutdown" and "Restart" button's bring up the "Shutdown/Restart" dialog but upon clicking one of these options, does nothing. By nothing I mean, there is not even feedback from the UI that I've clicked the button until I move my mouse. After clicking either button, the dialog box remains open until I move my mouse at which time the dialog box is closed.

Steps attempted so far to troubleshoot:

- Install ConsoleKit
- Added the following to /etc/pam.d/common-auth:

  ```
  session optional pam_loginuid.so
  ```

Running:

```
sudo reboot
```

and

```
sudo shutdown -hP now
```

work as expected

I suspect the issue is related to ConsoleKit but I am not familiar enough with it or the process used for the Shutdown/Restart buttons in Unity to debug further. I have also tried tailing /var/log/* while attempting to shutdown and this came up empty.

**EDIT:**

It's come to my attention that Ubuntu uses dbus to facilitate the shutdown/restart functions from the menu. As such, I've enabled dbus debugging and [HERE IS THE OUTPUT OF:](http://fpaste.org/182118/31681791/)

```
sudo dbus-monitor --system
```

Could use some help making sense of it, though I'll continue trying to do so myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The solution was the following line missing from `/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
session    optional    pam_systemd.so
```

I can only assume that this line was added to common-session in a recent update and, because my pam files are managed via puppet, I had yet to reflect this on the template puppet was deploying.